# How can I run Bmesh ops interactively inside an operator with a popup?

Tags: python, add-on, bmesh, operator

I would like to add some bmesh operators to one of my operator class. The operator has pop up menu invoked by `return wm.invoke_props_dialog( self)` so the values are edited interactively.

Here is a relative portion of my code inside `execute`

```
def execute(self,context):
    me = bpy.context.object.data

    bm = bmesh.new()   # create an empty BMesh
    bm.from_mesh(me)   # fill it in from a Mesh


    bmesh.ops.smooth_vert(bm, verts=bm.verts, factor=self.smoothvertices, mirror_clip_x=False, mirror_clip_y=False, mirror_clip_z=False, clip_dist=0.0, use_axis_x=True, use_axis_y=True, use_axis_z=True)


    bm.to_mesh(me)
    bm.free()

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

This works but after couple fiddles Blender just disappears, I guess it makes sense in a way probably the memory is not handled well in this occasion.

What is the right way to handle an interactive smoothing or similar operations using the Bmesh operators inside an instance of a `bpy.types.Operator`?

Sample Operator Code (Use it on high res object in Object Mode)
https://paste.debian.net/hidden/e93c95b8/

This seems to be the end of the log when it crashes when run with debug flag. I also have remeshing prior to smooth and some others.

```
redo_cb: operator redo Remesh meshes
Warning: No mesh data to join
Error   : Unrecognized Exception
Address : 0x00007FFF87993FB8
Module  : C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
```

EDIT1: I wonder if this is more of an issue with the remesh operator than the bmesh operator.

EDIT2: My other suspicion is that hitting the default 32 undo step inside an operator might be the culprit.

thanks

Comment: Running in object mode?  Could you please post a minimal working version code? _ie_ one we can run to test ourselves.

Comment: @batFINGER  Yes I am running it as object mode operator. I added a trimmed down sample operator.

Comment: Hi. Please add your code directly into the question instead of linking to it.

Comment: Ray such post are plain unreadable because makes it hard to follow the whole post due to lenght, linking pastes is a legit posting method.